# Using __declspec(dllexport) instead of -EXPORT:

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll

I was looking at documentation for exporting functions, and it stated __declspec(dllexport) should be used before the command line version -EXPORT: if possible. I'm currently using the command line variant. In attempting to make these changes I'm trying to understand the correct implementation, but I'm running into problems.

DLL's header file:

```
#ifdef LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define PRINT_TEST(name) LIBRARY_API void name()
typedef PRINT_TEST(print_log);
// ^ What's the C++11 equivalent with the using keyword?
```

DLL's source file:

```
PRINT_TEST(PrintTest) {
    std::cout << "Testing DLL" << std::endl;
}
```

Application's source file:

```
print_test* printTest = reinterpret_cast<print_test*>(GetProcAddress(testDLL, "PrintTest"));
```

Is the issue because of __declspec(dllexport) is included in the typedef? Therefore the statement in the application's source file actually is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void (*print_test)() printTest = reinterpret_cast<print_test*>(GetProcAddress(testDLL, "PrintTest"));
```

I'm not getting any compiler errors or warnings.

Comment: I have a question, why are you getting your function from the .dll dynamically, instead of including the .dlls header file, and linking to the .dlls lib file?

Comment: Hard to guess what LIBRARY_API might be.  Using the /EXPORT linker option is one way to export an identifier from a DLL.  It is the most painful way to do it.  The next lesser painful way is by using a .def file.  By far the easiest is to apply the __declspec(dllexport) attribute in source code.  Take your pick, consider that easiest is the easier way.

Comment: What problems are you having? `GetProcAddress` returning NULL?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm testing out runtime-compiled C++.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, that is exactly what it is returning. Therefore I'm unsure if I am using _declspec(dllexport) in the correct manner.

Comment: "What's the C++11 equivalent with the using keyword?" Nothing. It's just a function declaration. You don't need the typedef at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you're exporting a C++ function, which has a mangled name.  You either need to pass that mangled name to GetProcAddress (never fun) or you need to unmangle the export using __stdcall in the function declaration

```
LIBRARY_API __stdcall void PrintTest
```

or with `extern "C"`.  `__stdcall` is simpler and changes the calling convention from C++ style to C style.  (This may require passing "_PrintTest" to GetProcAddress because of how C function names are exported.)

Comment: Thank you very much. The name mangling is the issue. I'm taking a look at the map file are these all the generated function signatures? If the function name and parameters never change is it guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: @Kookehs Correct on both questions.  The mangled names are listed in the map file, and the mangled name won't change unless the parameter types or return type changes.